# Ajax and Store - posting next url from check out form

Tags: expresso-store, ajax

Shall i use the similar approach to implement next step feature from detail cart page to next page - via next url.

This below code i am using in Add to cart from product detail page -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#considerthis').click(function() {
                var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
                var data = $(this.form).serialize();
                $.post(url, data, function() {
                    $('#ycgroup').load('/shop/_cart');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's the problem?